# How and when viewstate encoding or hashing is done in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

While studying about view state, it was said that, the view state value in hidden variable is base64 encoded or also hashed with mac value. So at the time, when the request is received by the server, the view state value is already encoded or hashed. So encoding and hashing is done before the request reaches server. So if they are able to encode or hash a particular value.encoding or hashing is possible even before the request is made or reaches the server, we can encode or hash each and every sensitive information in the form . Cos, using tools like fiddler, while the form is posted back , it reveals values of all the controls' value including password.

I don't know whether the question is correct or not. Kindly guide me.

Thanks in advance
Jonathon

Comment: The Viewstate itself isn't hashed; instead it's signed with the Viewstate MAC (Message Authentication Code) which involves a hash/digest procedure. The MAC signing is used to verify the viewstate wasn't modified by a malicious user or suffered data loss in transit.

Comment: @Dai Thanks for the comment. But my concern is not about hashing or encoding Viewstate,the concern is about when the hashing or encoding is done.Kindly see the image in http://oi62.tinypic.com/29xxab6.jpg. I used fiddler to capture the request.First one is a simple webform.Second, the request part taken from fiddler when request for page is done for the first time. The third, when I click submit button. It is also the request/ header part of the Postback event. It contains hashed/encoded Viewstate.It means, hashing/encoding is done.So when hashing/encoding is done.Kindly help me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The ViewState can contain data in several forms, e.g. strings, numbers, objects. In order to be able to transfer these data to the client on the response, the data need to be encoded in a string format, Base64 in this case. This doesn't have anything to do with encryption so you can view the information in Fiddler. By default, the ViewState is only encrypted if a control on the Page requests it (for details see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479501.aspx)).

The purpose of the ViewState is to store data in the page itself, send them to the client and receive the data again when the client posts the form to the server. Several mechanisms in ASP.NET build upon the ViewState. For instance, the text of a TextBox is stored in the ViewState when the page is sent to the client. When the PostBack reaches the server, the request contains both current text of the TextBox that might have been changed by the user. Also, the previous text of the TextBox is contained in the ViewState. The framework then compares the old value to the new one and raises the TextChanged event is any changes have been made.

It is important that the ViewState is not changed on the client as this could have severe effects on the application and its security. That's why a hash value is generated over the ViewState before the response is sent to the client. The hash value is contained in the response along with the ViewState. When the PostBack reaches the server, this hash value is used to check whether the ViewState has been changed at the client ("ViewState tampering"). In this case, an error is raised and the request is not processed.

For detailed information on the ViewState see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the comment.Kindly see the image in http://oi62.tinypic.com/29xxab6.jpg. I used fiddler to capture the request.First one is a simple webform. Second one is the request part taken from fiddler when request for page is done for the first time. The third image is, when I click submit button. It is also the request/ header part of the Postback event. It contains hashed/encoded Viewstate.It means, hashing/encoding is done.So when hashing/encoding is done is my real doubt. Kindly help me if I am wrong.

Comment: @JonathonGohan: Hashing ansd Encoding is done on the server just before the response is sent to the client. The client should never change ViewState - if it does it is a security issue. This also implies that the client should never create/change hash values or encode the ViewState.